# How to set the cell value for displayed cells only?

Tags: vcl, delphi-10.3-rio

I have some data I want to display in a StringGrid. This data contains many rows with some pretty static columns but also two columns that need web-API lookups and take some time to gather. SO when I try to set these cells in the OnShow of the StringGrid (or any other "Init") I get a long delay until the cell values are set.
What I would like to do is only look up the values for those cells that are currently displayed (and not all of them at once).

How Do I find out which rows are currently displayed? Is there an event I can use?

Comment: There is no event specifically for that purpose. But you could use the `OnDrawCell` event to know when a cell is about to be drawn. If it doesn't have a value yet, and it is not in process of being downloaded, then kick off a thread to download it, and draw a pending status in the meantime. When the download is finished, update the cell value and invalidate the cell to trigger a repaint so the new value is displayed.

Comment: Thank you @RemyLebeau. Is there a way to have Delphi draw the cell after I updated the value? I dont want to go through the hastle of finding font and size and all that stuff... :-/

Comment: I already told you how to do that: "*When the download is finished, update the cell value and **invalidate the cell to trigger a repaint** so the new value is displayed.*" `TStringGrid` has `Invalidate()` and `InvalidateCell()` methods. Let the grid draw cells normally (`DefaultDrawing=True`), you are using the event only to kick off your downloads.